# What is the most efficient way to find pattern in inner axis of np array and modify it?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3d array [[[]]]. I want to look at all the arrays on the last axis or the inner most axis. If they match this pattern [x,x,x,x] I want to change them to [0,0,0,0]. I know what I want to do. I just don't know the most efficient method to do this.

Current Code:

```
most_common = np.array(stats.mode(img_arr)[0][0][0])
        for i, row in enumerate(img_arr):
            for j, color in enumerate(row):
                if np.array_equal(color, most_common):
                    img_arr[i][j] = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to subtract your pattern from the last axis and check norm=0:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(3*3*3).reshape(3,3,3)
b = np.array([0,1,2])
c = np.array([99,98,97])
indices = np.sum(np.abs(a-b), axis=2) == 0
a[indices] = c
print(a)
```